# Facebook share problem after impleme HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, https, facebook, facebook-graph

I had a company blog site http://blog.mysite.com, which was getting good traffic. On an average each blog had 200 fb shares(some had 2000+). And my alexa rank was 11000 in my country that time.

Then I added SSL on my blog site, also added redirect condition on my .htaccess file to redirect all request to https://blog.mysite.com, But since facebook treats both http and https version of any url different. I had lost all my count. Still my new blogs are geeting significant traffic and share. Also my sites alexa rank became to 20,000.

But I dont want to start with share count zero for my older blogs. Is there any way to so that i can tell facebook that these urls are same and show previous share count for https version also. and if someone share n https increase in the share count, dont start from zero.

My website is on wordpress.And somewhere I have heard that to change "og:url" meta tag to http but i dont know how to change that for each wordpress blog. Any help would be appericiated.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to create a 301 permanent redirect from http to your https in your .htaccess file. (This method will update most social sites IE Google +1)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://yourdomain/$1 [R,L]
```

**EDIT:** 
This method will regain FB likes and shares.
You can refresh it with  [FB debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

Comment: if you are aware www.mysite.com and blog.mysite.com both are 2 different subdomain of a domain mysite.com. www.mysite.com is runnning fine and is a seprate product. blog.mysite.com is a wordpress blog site where I have sharing problem. and it can't be www.blog.mysite.com.

Comment: Then resort to my first part. 301 redirect from http to https.

Comment: i have done that, that is what causing problem of loss in sharing count. since urls of each blog is changed from http://blo.mysite.com/some-blog-page to https://blo.mysite.com/some-blog-page and facebook treats both f them differently.

Comment: You said you added SSL. You have no mention of creating a 301 redirect. Big difference. A 301 redirect is the solution and it will take some time to propagate through systems, such as FB. You will gain your rank/credit back.

Comment: @AbdulKhalid see edit.

Comment: I have done this. I think you haven't got the problem. Actually suppose you have a url http://blog.ketchupp.in/5-facts-you-didnt-know-about-chef-imtiaz-qureshi/ and it has share count 2015. then you add the 301 redirect condition due to which when someone open above url it will actually open https://blog.ketchupp.in/5-facts-you-didnt-know-about-chef-imtiaz-qureshi/. In the above scenrio facebook gives share count of https version of url not http version. which is sth 27 only. I want user to show share count of old url or sum of share counts of both urls.

Comment: My edit was: You can refresh it with FB debugger. Link is in my original post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45179/discussion-between-norcal-johnny-and-abdul-khalid).